# Convert from json encoded string to [value, value],[value, value]

Tags: javascript, php, flot

I'm trying to chart data from my SQL database using flot, this is gathered using php then json encoded.

Currently looks like:

```
 [{"month":"February","data":482},{"month":"March","data":0}]
```

however for flot to operate the data needs to be in the form of

```
[X AXIS VALUE, Y AXIS VALUE],[X AXIS VALUE, Y AXIS VALUE],[X AXIS VALUE, Y AXIS VALUE]
```

ETC..

How might i convert that?

Comment: I would start by showing the structure your data currently have otherwise its quite hard to tell you how achieve the structure you want

Comment: convert what to what? There's only the output, what's the input and what have you tried?

Comment: Added the output to the post, sorry completely forgot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is to convert the data to an array (or object, if you prefer) and then pull out each plot point's data and shove it into an array.  Then, turn that array back into a string.  Here's an example:

```
// SAMPLE DATA
$json_string = '[{"month":"February","data":482},{"month":"March","data":0}]';

// DEFAULT
$all_points_array = array();

// JSON DECODE THE STRING AND TURN IT INTO AN ARRAY
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, true);

// LOOP THROUGH THE PLOT POINTS AND ADD EACH SET TO AN ARRAY
foreach ($json_array AS $plot_points) {
    $all_points_array[] = '['.$plot_points['month'].','.$plot_points['data'].']';
}

// CONVERT THE ARRAY TO A STRING, SEPARATED BY COMMAS
$all_points = implode(',', $all_points_array);

// PRINT OUT YOUR STRING
echo $all_points;
```

Comment: I'm sorry; this is on the server side.  Looks like you are looking for a way to do this client side from the JSON returned from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array:

```
var flotData = data.map(function (el) {
  return [el.month, el.data];
});

console.log(flotData); // [["February", 482], ["March", 0]]
```